# Почему в карте Конструктора на мобильном скрываются элементы управления

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-embed

На сайте у меня поставлена карта с отметкой организации. В полноэкранном режиме можно прокладывать маршрут прям на сайте, а на смартфонах - нужно обязательно открывать карту яндекса.

Comment: дайте ссылку на страницу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На этом сайте вставлена карта Конструктора - такие виджеты нельзя кастомизировать и они автоматически подстраиваются под размер экрана/страницы, в том числе может меняться набор доступных элементов управления.

На мобильном устройстве карте недостаточно места, чтобы появилась панель маршрутов.

Вы можете создать нужную карту самостоятельно через JS API и добавить те элементы управления, которые нужны.

Если вы хотите, чтобы маршруты можно было строить только до вашей организации, можно получить Виджет с этой картой в iframe (перейти на Яндекс.Карты и получить код в блоке "Поделиться"). [Вот так](https://jsfiddle.net/r481f5Lw/):

```
<iframe src="https://yandex.ru/map-widget/v1/-/CBqlUKSJKA" width="560" height="400" frameborder="1" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```